# I have trouble pushing a object using updateOne() (mongoose)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have this issue:

Im trying to push a object using mongoose but I can´t.

I wanna push a object on "products: []" using a especific id, this is the function but is not working :/. I'm learning mongoose and I'm having troubles

```
async editCart(obj, id) {
    try {
      await this.model.updateOne(
        { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
        { $push: { products: obj } }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

```
[
    {
        "_id": "62cb91701b4c5b51f263e099",
        "products": [],
        "timeStamp": "10/7/2022 22:56:48",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "62cb918b1b4c5b51f263e09c",
        "products": [],
        "timeStamp": "10/7/2022 22:57:15",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: `this.model.updateOne` returns a result object. What is it printing to the console?

Comment: @prasad_ it print ```acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
```

Comment: What is the model's schema description.

Comment: @prasad_ ```const ProductModel = mongoose.model(
    'cart', 
    new mongoose.Schema({
        products: [{ type: String }],
        timeStamp: {type: String}
    })
);```

Comment: @prasad_ i found the problem, iun the schema i put array hahah and it work

Answer (score 0):

Try using `findByIdAndUpdate`:

```
async editCart(obj, id) {
  try {
    const updated = await this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: { products: obj } }, { new: true });
    console.log(updated)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: it worked I had problem with my schema